# Chef: WARN: Node has an empty run list

Tags: chef-infra, chef-zero

I'm running into an issue with Chef zero; odd thing is that i have been provisioning many nodes this way without actually changing stuff but now it has broken.

```
(python)➜  chef_files git:(develop) ✗ knife node list 
feeder2

(python)➜  chef_files git:(develop) ✗ knife node show feeder2
Node Name:   feeder2
Environment: production
FQDN:        
IP:          
Run List:    role[base], role[feeder]
Roles:       
Recipes:     
Platform:     
Tags:  

(python)➜  chef_files git:(develop) ✗ knife role list
base
feeder

(python)➜  chef_files git:(develop) ✗ knife zero converge --config <...>/chef_files/.chef/knife.rb  --ssh-user ec2-user --identity-file <...>.pem -P "$login_password" name:feeder2
INFO: Using configuration from <...>/chef_files/.chef/knife.rb
INFO: Remote command: sudo chef-client -S http://127.0.0.1:18889
INFO: Using configuration from <...>/chef_files/.chef/knife.rb
INFO: Started chef-zero at http://localhost:8889 with repository at .
  One version per cookbook
  clients at <...>/chef_files/clients
  cookbooks at <...>/chef_files/cookbooks, <...>/chef_files/site-cookbooks
  data_bags at <...>/chef_files/data_bags
  environments at <...>/chef_files/environments
  nodes at <...>/chef_files/nodes
  roles at <...>/chef_files/roles
  users at <...>/chef_files/users
  policies at <...>/chef_files/policies
    Starting Chef Client, version 12.16.42
    resolving cookbooks for run list: []
    Synchronizing Cookbooks:
    Installing Cookbook Gems:
    Compiling Cookbooks...
    [2017-02-11T15:30:04+00:00] WARN: Node feeder2 has an empty run list.
    Converging 0 resources
```

I have checked but the role/node json files are all there....

Any tips/help is appreciated!
Paul

Answer (score -1):

Issue resolved however i don't fully understand it yet.... at some point when chef-zero (server) failed, i tried to fix it by running a new server as deamon or manually from the terminal. This instance is however empty and does not get filled by chef zero.

It got resolved after i stopped all chef-zero instances and started converge; this created a new instance which is then populated so the runlist and all is known.

Paul